# What insect is this? Found this at home, India

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
Found this insect in Kolkata India. Has a sting at its rear end. The wings are shiny.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please edit your post to add an estimate for the size of this insect and the nearby environment as those factors can be helpful clues for identifications. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4):

That is a parasitic wasp in the family, [Ichneumonidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichneumonidae). You can tell by looking for a cell in the forewing that looks like a horse head. The "stinger" is an ovipositor. These wasps lay their eggs in the larvae of other insects

Comment: I've been trying to work out which species of wasp in that family it is. Going by photos on https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/17352592 it looks like this could be a female Xanthopimpla punctata ("Yellow Ichneumon Wasp"), but there seem to be a lot of very similar looking Xanthopimpla species it could also be.